# one extra series is created in chart in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, applescript

In excel 2011 ,One extra series is created using apple script.

```
   tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    make new workbook
    tell worksheet "sheet1" of active workbook
        set value of cell "A1" to 10
        set value of cell "B1" to 5
        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {left position:100,      top:100, height:200, width:300, name:"MyChart"}
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object "MyChart"
        tell ochart1
            set chart type to bar clustered
            make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1", name:"2"}

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

My problem, one extra series(i.e Series 1) is created in sheet1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: New charts typically have a series when created, so you need to delete any existing series before adding the new one

Comment: please run my script, at a time two series is created.

Comment: If this statement                                                 make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1", name:"2"} , three series is created i.e two series is extra created.

Comment: I can't run your script - no Mac here

Comment: but my script is run successfully on mac machine (os version -10.6.8)

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. After playing with this for a while I am beginning to suspect a bug in Microsoft Excel... it wouldn't be the first.

Comment: ok, I want to change the series color using apple script,what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't the right way of doing it, but it should get the job done.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    make new workbook
    tell worksheet "sheet1" of active workbook
        set value of cell "A1" to 10
        set value of cell "B1" to 5
        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {left position:100, top:100, height:200, width:300, name:"MyChart"}
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object "MyChart"
        tell ochart1
            set chart type to bar clustered
            make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1", name:"2"}
            delete (every series whose name ≠ "2")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: If this statement make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1"} , three series is created i.e two series is extra created.My problem is, My script is successfully run in case column to row . but in case while increment the column to column my script is fail. if my cell range is A1 to c1 then 3 series is created and if range is A1 to D1 then 4 series is created.

Comment: if i am run script which contain two make series statement.    first is->  make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1"} and second is make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$c$1"} . in case 5 series is created i.e 3 series are extra created . How can i am identify 3 series are deleted.

Comment: see second screen shot is attached with 5 series,In case threes series series1,series3,series4 are extra created and how can identify series1 series 3 and series 4 are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that things work fine when you create a more meaningful series:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    make new workbook
    tell worksheet "sheet1" of active workbook
        set value of cell "A1" to 2
        set value of cell "B1" to 3
        set value of cell "A2" to 4
        set value of cell "B2" to 6
        set value of cell "A3" to 10
        set value of cell "B3" to 5
        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {left position:100, top:100, height:200, width:300, name:"MyChart"}
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object "MyChart"
        tell ochart1
            set chart type to bar clustered
            #remove  first series
            make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3", name:"one"}
            make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3", name:"two"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Note - I created the series separately, because I could not figure out how to give them each a name in a single statement.

Comment: In case ,if series range is =Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1 then two series is extra created.